# Prove equivalence of two statements related the vector field $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $M$ and $N$ be linear subspaces of $V$. Prove that

(a) if $y\in M$, $z\in N$ and $y+z=\theta$ then $y=z=\theta$

is equivalent to

(b) if $y+z = y^{\prime}+z^{\prime}$, where $y,y^{\prime}\in M$ and $z,z^{\prime}\in N$, then $y=y^{\prime}$ and $z=z^{\prime}$.

Note: $\theta$ is the "zero" element of $V$.

Proof.

Now statement (a) is something like $P\Rightarrow Q$, which is equivalent to $\neg P \lor Q.$ Statement (b) is something like $R\Rightarrow S$. Thus we need to prove that $(\neg P \lor Q)\Rightarrow (R\Rightarrow S)$, which in words says that, assuming either $P$ false or $Q$ true (or both) and $R$ true, leads to $S$ true.

Concretely, by (a), $y=z=\theta$, and by the assumption of (b), $y+z = y^{\prime}+z^{\prime} = \theta+\theta=\theta.$ Thus $y^{\prime} = -z^\prime$. But this does not seem to work.

Am I messing-up the logics?

Comment: Doesn't $y'+z' = \theta$ implies by (a) that $y' =z' = \theta$? If you choose to assume (a) true then it must apply. You are changing your assumption by writing $y' =-z'$

Comment: This, in turn, means that $y' =y$ and $z'=z$ as required. Does that help?

Comment: I'm actually already using (a) as $x=y=\theta$, which leads to $y^{\prime}+z^{\prime}=\theta+\theta=\theta$. Are you saying that I need to use (a) also for $y^{\prime}$ and $z^{\prime}$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: Ok, but if I assume $y=z=\theta$ and $y^{\prime}=z^{\prime}=\theta$, then $y=y^{\prime} = z = z^{\prime}$ without even requiring that $y+z = y^{\prime}+z^{\prime}$, which however in this case is satisfied anyway...

Comment: No, you didn't assume $y' =z' =\theta$, you deduced it using statement (a). You only assumed statement (a) is true.

Comment: ok, but still, as far as I can see, the conclusion is reached without using the fact that $y+z = y^{\prime}+z^{\prime}$, which seems puzzeling..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to prove that the two statements are equivalent, i.e. $(a) \Leftrightarrow (b)$. We prove one by one:

1) $(a) \Rightarrow (b)$. Assume (a) is true then $y+z = \theta \Rightarrow y =z = \theta$. Now we want to show that if $y+z =y'+z'$ , then $y =y'$ and $z = z'$. Since we already have that $y=z = \theta$ , therefore $y+z =\theta+\theta =\theta $ and if $y+z = y'+z' \Rightarrow y'+z' = \theta$. Now statement (a) is assumed to be true. So this in turn implies that $y'=z' =\theta$ and this proves $(a) \Rightarrow (b)$.

2) $(b) \Rightarrow (a)$. Suppose $(b)$ is true. We want to show $(a)$ holds i.e. if $y+z =\theta$ then $y =z = \theta$. So if $y+z =\theta \Rightarrow y+z =\theta+\theta$ which by $(b)$ being true in turn implies that $y= \theta, z =\theta$, hence proving the claim in part $(a)$.

Therefore $(a) \Leftrightarrow (b)$.

Comment: Does that clarify your doubt? Note the careful assumption of statements. What we assume to be true and what we need to show.